# How to pass a line of .txt file as an input to makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile and I want to add a new target which can read a specific line of a .txt file and do the process from $4 onwards.

I already have run the code and made the database out of the images in URLs and converted them as well ($2 and $3).

By the way, if you think it is not a reasonable way to do it (pass specific inputs and collect corresponding outputs), please let me know how is it possible to be done in a reasonable fashion?

```
    #Setup test images and check target
    #
    #URLS of images to test
    IMAGE_URLS=     http://farm1.static.flickr.com/93/238836380_a4db5526a9.jpg \
            http://farm1.static.flickr.com/203/495381063_67fe69a64f.jpg \
            http://farm1.static.flickr.com/93/238836380_a4db5526a9.jpg \
            http://farm1.static.flickr.com/203/495381063_67fe69a64f.jpg \
            http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2068/2218230147_c6559cd7ac.jpg \
            http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1020/1459940961_6a54469e1e.jpg \
            http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1140/1026808473_e4a2a76ded.jpg \
            http://farm1.static.flickr.com/143/341257611_e730dfea3d.jpg \
            http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2079/2226345732_0152a169fd.jpg \
            http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2168/1834178819_e866ed3c04.jpg \
            http://farm1.static.flickr.com/149/409910004_068c0fdec1.jpg \
    #Classification index of test images (not important)
    CLASS_IDX=      281\
            281\
            285\
            291\
            728\
            279\
            285\
            281\
            281

    # Getters
    JOINED   = $(join $(addsuffix @,$(IMAGE_URLS)),$(CLASS_IDX))
    GET_URL  = $(word 1,$(subst @, ,$1))
    GET_IDX  = $(word 2,$(subst @, ,$1))

    #Bash coloring
    RED=\033[0;31m
    GREEN=\033[0;32m
    NC=\033[0m

    #$1=URL $2=NAME $3=CONVERTED_PNG $4=CHECK $5=IDX

    define IMAGE_BUILD_RULES

    #download image
    $2:
        wget "$(strip $1)" -O $2

    #convert
    $3:$2
        convert $2 -resize 224x224! $3

    #check if correct class is identified. If not error
    $4:$3 $(EXE)
        @echo "Evaluating image $3"
        ./$(EXE) $3 | tee $4
        @grep -q "Detected class: $(strip $5)" $4 && echo "$(GREEN)correctly identified image $2$(NC)" ||  (echo "$(RED)Did not correctly identify image $2$(NC)")

    endef

    #check if all images are classified correctly
    check_all: $(foreach URL, $(IMAGE_URLS), check_$(basename $(notdir $(URL))))
        @echo "$(GREEN)All correct!$(NC)"

    #define build rules for all images
    $(foreach j,$(JOINED),$(eval $(call IMAGE_BUILD_RULES,\
        $(call GET_URL, $j),\
        $(notdir $(call GET_URL, $j)),\
        converted_$(basename $(notdir $(call GET_URL, $j))).png,\
        check_$(basename $(notdir $(call GET_URL, $j))),\
        $(call GET_IDX,$j)\
    )))
```

Comment: *Which* line of this file do you want Make to read?

Comment: Actually this is an old makefile. I think I need a new target which can read the .txt file and pass corresponding (pre-downloaded) image to the makefile to do from $4 onwards. (In the .txt file I have stored the name of images and their corresponding index)( I assume in new make file $4 does not depend on $3 and $2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps much, but it seems you are rethinking your question anyway. Your makefile looks like it is doing some kind of build management, at least remotely. (Note that you could write your rule with patterns, but you seem to aim for something different.) The following rewrite of your makefile uses the [GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which looks like a good fit for your purpose:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

# Direct definition of the table in the file:
# define IMAGES :=
# 2
# http://farm1.static.flickr.com/93/238836380_a4db5526a9.jpg       281
# http://farm1.static.flickr.com/203/495381063_67fe69a64f.jpg    281
# http://farm1.static.flickr.com/93/238836380_a4db5526a9.jpg     285
# http://farm1.static.flickr.com/203/495381063_67fe69a64f.jpg    291
# http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2068/2218230147_c6559cd7ac.jpg      728
# http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1020/1459940961_6a54469e1e.jpg      279
# http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1140/1026808473_e4a2a76ded.jpg      285
# http://farm1.static.flickr.com/143/341257611_e730dfea3d.jpg    281
# http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2079/2226345732_0152a169fd.jpg      281
# http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2168/1834178819_e866ed3c04.jpg    ???
# http://farm1.static.flickr.com/149/409910004_068c0fdec1.jpg      ???
# endef

# Reading table from a file. File *must* be two columns (url, class) and nothing else - no comments either!
IMAGES := $(file < imagelist.txt)
$(info Processing file list:$(newline)$(IMAGES))
IMAGES := 2 $(IMAGES) # add the number of columns in front to make it a gmtt table

#Bash coloring
RED=\033[0;31m
GREEN=\033[0;32m
NC=\033[0m

#$1=URL $2=NAME $3=CONVERTED_PNG $4=CHECK $5=IDX
define IMAGE_BUILD_RULES
#download image
$2:
    wget "$(strip $1)" -O $2

#convert
$3:$2
    convert $2 -resize 224x224! $3

#check if correct class is identified. If not error
$4:$3 $(EXE)
    @echo "Evaluating image $3"
    ./$(EXE) $3 | tee $4
    @grep -q "Detected class: $(strip $5)" $4 && echo "$(GREEN)correctly identified image $2$(NC)" ||  (echo "$(RED)Did not correctly identify image $2$(NC)")

endef

#check if all images are classified correctly
check_all: $(foreach URL, $(IMAGE_URLS), check_$(basename $(notdir $(URL))))
    @echo "$(GREEN)All correct!$(NC)"


# Just as a check for now, remove the whole $(info ...) if output too large    
$(info Generating the following rules: $(newline)$(call map-select,1 2,$(IMAGES),t,$$(call IMAGE_BUILD_RULES,$$1,$$(notdir $$1),converted_$$(basename $$(notdir $$1)).png,check_$$(basename $$(notdir $$1)),$$2)))

# Rule definition - no need to call $(eval)
# Use the function `map-select` which applies a function on each selected line of a table. Syntax is $(call map-select,_column-numbers_,_table_,_where-clause_,_mapping-function_)
# We select columns one and two of the table. Where-clause is always true (t). Function is calling IMAGE_BUILD_RULES with the selected columns enumerated as $1,$2,$3,etc. - this parameter must be quoted ($$)
$(call map-select,1 2,$(IMAGES),t,$$(call IMAGE_BUILD_RULES,$$1,$$(notdir $$1),converted_$$(basename $$(notdir $$1)).png,check_$$(basename $$(notdir $$1)),$$2))
```

The referenced file `imagelist.txt` must look like this:

```
http://farm1.static.flickr.com/93/238836380_a4db5526a9.jpg       281
http://farm1.static.flickr.com/203/495381063_67fe69a64f.jpg      281
http://farm1.static.flickr.com/93/238836380_a4db5526a9.jpg   285
http://farm1.static.flickr.com/203/495381063_67fe69a64f.jpg      291
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2068/2218230147_c6559cd7ac.jpg    728
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1020/1459940961_6a54469e1e.jpg    279
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1140/1026808473_e4a2a76ded.jpg    285
http://farm1.static.flickr.com/143/341257611_e730dfea3d.jpg      281
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2079/2226345732_0152a169fd.jpg    281
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2168/1834178819_e866ed3c04.jpg    ???
http://farm1.static.flickr.com/149/409910004_068c0fdec1.jpg      ???
```

Notice that your testdata has duplicate URLs in it.